# Ggplot facet like graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2

You can download my dataset [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lwcdpvqq9zg39er/biveri3.csv?dl=0)

I'm trying to make a graph like this facet one but instead of two graphs I want to draw this in one.

[image]

But I also want it looks like facets. I mean when I draw this in one graph it look like this. 
[image]

I don't want these two side by side. I want them in one bar. Like this one! :-)
[image]

My code:

```
bb <- ggplot(biveri3, aes(x = bio8, fill = as.factor(varyok)))
bb + geom_histogram(data = biveri3, position = "dodge")
```

Comment: The question is not clear both in the title and the text. You like it to look like facets, but not the actual facets. Can you clarify a little bit?

Comment: I honestly can't understand what you want. Can you edit to make it more clear? If you are saying you want a graph that looks like the 3rd one, then don't you have it already? If you want the bars side by side on the same axis, how is that possible when their x axis ranges overlap?

Comment: You mean like `bb + geom_histogram(data = biveri3, alpha=.5, position="identity")`?

Comment: having `dput(biveri3)` wld help.

Comment: lukeA thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to lukeA I did what I want.

bb + geom_histogram(data = biveri3, alpha=.5, position="identity")?